# something wrong about scipy and numpy, when i import scipy.stats.linregress

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, typeerror

When I import `scipy.stats.linregress`, to do something about ols, there is a `TypeError`.

When I run my code in PyCharm, all is OK. There is no error and I can get the right results.

But when I debug my code, I got a `TypeError`.

Python 3.10.1 amd64

numpy 1.22.0 amd64

scipy 1.7.3 amd64

My code looks like this:

```
from scipy import stats
results = stats.linregress(low.loc[ind], high.loc[ind])
```

and the error info like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 516, in __init__
    self.dtype = numeric.dtype(int_type)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\workspace\python\tuvn\my_funcs\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from my_funcs.get_rsrs import get_rsrs
  File "D:\workspace\python\tuvn\my_funcs\get_rsrs.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 441, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from ._procrustes import procrustes
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_procrustes.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import orthogonal_procrustes
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 195, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .lapack import get_lapack_funcs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\lapack.py", line 990, in <module>
    _int32_max = _np.iinfo(_np.int32).max
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 518, in __init__
    self.dtype = numeric.dtype(type(int_type))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [mcve] and [ask] in order to improve your post. Mainly, we need a sample of your input data, more context on your environment switch, the expected output. Properly stating a problem and writing a sound question is more than 95% of work done towards the solution.

Comment: I'm getting the same error inside PyCharm's Jupyter host.

Comment: Have you read links above?

Comment: I've run into a similar problem, this is most probably caused by a bug in pandas, see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41935

@xinyangq, are you using pandas before these imports reported above?