# In debug, using pandas before importing from Scipy generates Type error on import

Tags: python, scipy, python-import

When run in debug in PyCharm 2021.3 (Community Edition) on Mac, the code:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame()
from scipy.stats import poisson
```

Generates the exception:

```
...
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 518, in __init__
    self.dtype = numeric.dtype(type(int_type))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

(the `None` variable is `numeric.dtype`)

Python 3.10.0
dependencies: `pip install numpy==1.21.2 pandas==1.3.5 scipy==1.7.3`

Comment: Also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70588672/something-wrong-about-scipy-and-numpy-when-i-import-scipy-stats-linregress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known (but not solved) issue; see [pandas issue 41935](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41935) on github.  Some comments there suggest it might be a Python or [Cython bug](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4609).

Comment: Is there any workaround at all? I've been running into this issue a lot