# np.random.choice Throws Exception when p Value Provided

Tags: python, numpy

I can call `np.random.choice(5, 3)` with success:

[image]

However, adding any `p` values (e.g. `np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])`) throws an exception:

[image]

These examples are directly from [Numpy's Documentation for np.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

I am running python 3.10.0:
[image]

I have the latest (1.22.4) version of Numpy at the time of writing:
[image]

I have tracked this down to `np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])` works right up until a call to `pd.read_sql`, then fails immediately after running that line of code.

Comment: You may need to worry about numpy version than python version. The doc says *New in version 1.7.0.*. You code works fine on my system.

Comment: What is the output of `type(np.random.choice)`? Also please don't use screenshots, copy paste the **text** of your code/error messages

Comment: Output of `type(np.random.choice)` is `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

Comment: I am running the `np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])` against the debugger. What is inexplicably strange is that the code works immediately before executing a line of code that calls an imported function that just calls a SQL script and generates a DataFrame from it. Immediately after executing that line, the `np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])` call gives the `{TypeError}'NoneType' object is not callable` error.

Comment: There was a Cython bug that affected some builds of numpy.  Try running your code without the debugger.

Comment: `np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])` does work on its own! However, after running `pd.read_sql(query, mydb)` (where `query` is a simple SQL query and `mydb` is a `mysql.connector` connection), the exact same call (`np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])`) fails with `{TypeError}'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929565/in-debug-using-pandas-before-importing-from-scipy-generates-type-error-on-impor (and follow the links for the latest updates).

Comment: If you have Python 3.10, try to use pandas==1.4.3 and numpy==1.23.0
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52137/Debugger-fails-with-numpy-getlimits-TypeError-NoneType-object-is-not-callable#focus=Comments-27-6215565.0-0

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be with the version of numpy please check it once as the piece of code is working fine for me

```
import numpy as np
print(np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0]))
```

output

```
[0 3 0]
```

my numpy version is **1.21.2**

Comment: mine version was 1.21.2

Comment: I just tried downgrading to 1.21.2 and I am getting the same error.

Comment: actually you can see its working on some online compilers i am testing the part of code there only. I think its not issue of the numpy.

import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
print(np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0]))


output:


1.22.0
[0 3 3]

Comment: can you check if you have by mistake not declared np or if the np variable is reassigned somewhere as none

Comment: I have not, as calling `np.random.choice(5, 3)` still works successfully.